# Wired Xbox One controller not working on Ubuntu 18.04 (Kernel 5.4)

Tags: 18.04, drivers, usb, kernel, games

Whenever I try to connect my Xbox One controller via USB (I don't have a Bluetooth adapter or anything), it just vibrates briefly, and then nothing happens. It doesn't light up nor are any of the inputs recognised.

It's recognised when I type `lsusb`:

```
Bus 010 Device 007: ID 045e:02d1 Microsoft Corp. XBOX One Controller for Windows
```

Here's the output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux cobradabest-ubuntu-pc 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried using different USB ports and cables, and it made no difference.

What do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the issue, all I had to do was type "sudo modprobe xpad" in the terminal.

Comment: The reason why you need to do this is probably that you experimented with the `xone` driver. It installs file `/etc/modprobe.d/xone-blacklist.conf` that blacklists `xpad`. If you want to restore the original functionality, be sure to uninstall `xone` using the provided `uninstall.sh` script.